# Show submitted form response on the same page. (No Reload)

Tags: php, forms, jquery

How would I go about showing the response from a submitted contact form (on the same page underneath the form) rather than sending the user to a new page after the submission?

I have seen some people creating a div element, and then putting the received response into it. Is that a recommended approach?

Here is what I have so far:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$name =$_GET['name'];
$email =$_GET['name'];
$message =$_GET['name'];

$to = "support@loaidesign.co.uk";
$subject = "";
$message = "";
$headers = "From: $email";

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
    echo "<h2>Thank you for your comment</h2>";
}
else{
    echo "<h2>Sorry, there has been an error</2>";
}

?>
```

and here is the **HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapperB">
                <div class="content">
                    <form id="contactForm" action="assets/email.php" method="get">

                        <label  for="name">Your Name</label>
                        <input  name="name" id="name" type="text" required placeholder="Please enter your name">

                        <label  for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input  name="email" id="email" type="email" required placeholder="Please enter your email address here">

                        <label  for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>  

                        <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button> 
                    </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
```

Comment: You use the word `responds`. Could you define that for us?
Did you mean `response`?

Comment: The respond text are these two: echo "<h2>Thank you for your comment</h2>"; } else{ echo "<h2>Sorry, there has been an error</2>";

And I want to show them on the same page / div not on a new page.

Comment: Sorry, this was a misunderstanding from my side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a working example using the [suggested example from the *JQuery* site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#example-7) and **[pajaja's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171064)** answer.

### Solution:

Place this in the **`<head>`** of your webpage.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

**OR**

Download *JQuery* and include it the same way.

### Form:

Your contact form remains un-changed.

```
<form id="contactForm" action="assets/email.php" Method="POST">
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" required placeholder="Please enter your name">

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Please enter your email address here">

    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" required></textarea>  

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

### Returned Data:

Add your response element where you want in the body.

`<div id="contactResponse"></div>`

### Javascript:

Now place (preferably just before **`</body>`**) the javascript code:

```
<script>
     $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) 
     {
         /* stop form from submitting normally */
         event.preventDefault();

         /* get some values from elements on the page: */
         var $form = $( this ),
             $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
             name_value = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
             email_value = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
             message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
             url = $form.attr('action');

         /* Send the data using post */
         var posting = $.post( url, { 
                           name: name_value, 
                           email: email_value, 
                           message: message_value 
                       });

         posting.done(function( data )
         {
             /* Put the results in a div */
             $( "#contactResponse" ).html(data);

             /* Change the button text. */
             $submit.text('Sent, Thank you');

             /* Disable the button. */
             $submit.attr("disabled", true);
         });
    });
</script>
```

### Action Script:

Your contact *(PHP)* file remains the same but change $_GET to $_POST:

```
<?php

    $name    = $_POST['name'];
    $email   = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to      = "xxx@xxx.xxx";
    $subject = "";
    $message = "";
    $headers = "From: $email";

    if( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) )
    {
        echo "<h2>Thank you for your comment</h2>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2>Sorry, there has been an error</h2>";
    }

?>
```

### Result:

This should now send the data from the form on submit and then display the returned data in the `#contactResponse` element. The button will also set the text to "Sent, Thank you" while also disabling the button.

Comment: Is there anyway if email posting is successful to change the send button from saying (Send to 'Sent, Thanks you') and change the CSS style? and if email is not successful just show an error?

Comment: @Leo See my revised answer above, hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, also I have noticed that you have removed the Method="Post" from the HTML, do I need to do that as well? as I have it on

Comment: @Leo As JQuery is taken over the submit event, and is now using ajax, the `Method="Post"` then becomes useless.
**Edit: 
On second thought, leave this in for non-javascript users.**

Comment: @Leo After checking in a debugger, it seems `.button("refresh");` **is not needed**, I have removed this in the example.

Comment: There is a small problem, when the form has been submitted the Send button will be disabled and it will say 'Sent, thank you'. Now on the PHP it also says to show ( echo "<h2>Thank you for your comment</h2>"; ). It's becoming a bit confusing, cant it be:

When submit and success - disable button and say 'Sent, thank you' Only, no need for the PHP success response, however if submit and fail - it will show the PHP echo "<h2>Sorry, there has been an error</h2>";

Comment: @Leo Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35225/discussion-between-avitex-and-leo)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use ajax for that. The simplest solution is to get `jQuery` javascript library an use it's `.post` function for which you can find documentation and examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). In your case it will look something like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var name_value = $("#name").val();
    var email_value = $("#email").val();
    var message_value = $("#message").val();
    $.post("assets/email.php", { name: name_value, email: email_value, message: message_value }).done(function(data) {
        $("#response").html(data);
    });
  });
})
</script>
```

Also your PHP code is wrong:

```
$name =$_GET['name'];
$email =$_GET['name'];
$message =$_GET['name']
```

You are getting `$_GET['name']` for all 3 variables.

**edit**:
I added a complete example but it is not tested it's just so you can have an idea how to do what you want. Also since this is using HTTP POST request, you will need to edit your PHP so it gets values `$_POST` array, not `$_GET`. Also you will need to add a `<div id="response"></div>` where you want to display the response.

Comment: When I did some research I have seen this solution and tried to implemented on what I have already, but I didn't get it to work, it's completely new to me, is there anyway you can show me how to implanted on my current code?

Answer (score 2):

You can just keep it on the same page. For example, if your form is on `contact.php`, just echo your code like so:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
   <input type='test' name='name' placeholder='Your name here' required='required' /><br />
   <input type='submit' value='submit' name='contact' />
</form>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['contact']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
      echo "You submitted this form with value ".$_POST['name'].".";
   }
?>
```

Of course this will reload that page. If you don't want the page to be reloaded, you need to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with the [Jquery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).  There's another [here](http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/).

[My use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744948/how-can-i-do-a-file-upload-and-return-results-to-the-same-page) was a lot more involved.  It included uploading a file along with some user entered fields and basic auth credentials in the header as well.  The Form plugin handled them all using the normal $.ajax fields.