# Bootstrap Popup on sending form data to mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working as junior web master maybe that's why I have come with a simple question here. I have designed a single page application for client which has contact form at the end of page, validation is done using bootstrap but to send form data to mail id only method I know is using php with action directing different page. since my website is single page application i would like a popup on successful submission to mail id

Below is the HTML code for the contact form

```
<form class="form-inline" data-toggle="validator" role="form" method="post" id="enquiry" action="index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Email Id</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control col-lg-12" id="exampleInputPassword3" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" required>
  </div>
  <br/> <br/>
  <div class=" col-lg-12 form-group">
    <textarea cols="80" placeholder="Enter query Here" class="form-control" name="query" id="address" data-error ="Please Enter Your Query" required></textarea><br/><br/>
  </div>
  <button style="background-color:#f15a24; color:#FFF;" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can use php to send form data and still get a pop up in same page?

Or do I need to use jquery to send data and pop-up?

It would be great if somebody helps me out with code, thanks in advance

**Updated**

below(index.php page) i have added the code what you have given,

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/creative.js"></script>
<script src="js/validator.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#enquiry").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $('#enquiry').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(ret) {
            if(ret === "Success"){ alert("Success"); }else{ alert("Failed"); }
            //Failure message if ret is false
          });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this js to your script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enquiry").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var dataString = $('#enquiry').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(ret) {
        if(ret === "Success")
        { 
          alert("Success"); 
        } else { 
          alert("Failed"); 
        }
       } 
     });
    }
  );
});
```

submit.php contains the code to send and exit it with the success (true) or failure (false) message. That will be caught in `ret` variable.

Comment: can please help me out with submit.php code, I have just started my career in jquery or javascript, it would be great help if you do so

Comment: I can help you for sure, but try first, if there arises problem I would

Comment: <?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $insert = "insert into TABLE_NAME values('$name','$last_name')";// Do Your Insert Query
  if(mysql_query($insert)) {
   echo "Success";
  } else {
   echo "Cannot Insert";
  }
?>

Comment: Yes. Make sure that mysql is deprecated, try using mysqli or PDO

Comment: but i am not getting any pop up

Comment: Replace the comments with the alert/popup box [//Success message here if ret is true
            //Failure message if ret is false]

Comment: if(ret === true){
   alert("Success");
   }else{
   alert("Failed");
   }

Comment: this what i have used but still no pop up.

Comment: `ret` should have what you have printed in echo -- `Success` or `Cannot Insert`

Comment: `if(ret === "Success"){ alert("Success"); }else{ alert("Failed"); } `

Comment: same problem, no pop up

Comment: Update your question with the recent code so that I can explore

Comment: a small mistake! instead of       `    });
        }` use `          }
        }); ` after success

Comment: And in post where is the `last_name` in your form?

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#enquiry").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $('#enquiry').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(ret) {
            if(ret === true){
   alert("Success");
   }else{
   alert("Failed");
   }
            //Failure message if ret is false
          } });
        }
      });
    });
</script>

Comment: updated code i have added, even if there is no last name, i should get failure pop up isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I use the same here, I get failure popup

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browsers console screen?

Comment: Yes this what it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: check for the braces, opening and closing parenthesis, brackets,... that's simple to find. The error should be accompanied by the line number, check with that

Comment: Glad that I have helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**

This will be more detailed answer I was looking for, I thought it be would be helpful for somebody so I have  answered my own question as an alternative solution, check out the links below.

[Show submitted form response on the same page. (No Reload)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171017/show-submitted-form-response-on-the-same-page-no-reload)

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/submit-form-jquery-and-ajax.html